# Get minvalue of a Map(Key,Double)

Tags: java, guava

Is there a method (maybe with Google Collections) to obtain the min value of a `Map(Key, Double)`?

In the traditional way, I would have to sort the map according to the values, and take the first/last one.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the standard [`Collections#min()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29) for this.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
map.put("1.1", 1.1);
map.put("0.1", 0.1);
map.put("2.1", 2.1);

Double min = Collections.min(map.values());
System.out.println(min); // 0.1
```

**Update**: since you need the key as well, well, I don't see ways in [`Collections`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) or Google [`Collections2`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) API since a `Map` is not a `Collection`. The [`Maps#filterEntries()`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterEntries%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) is also not really useful, since you only know the actual result at *end* of iteration.

Most straightforward solution would then be this:

```
Entry<String, Double> min = null;
for (Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (min == null || min.getValue() > entry.getValue()) {
        min = entry;
    }
}

System.out.println(min.getKey()); // 0.1
```

(nullcheck on `min` left aside)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I forgot to mention that I need the key of the min value

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way, I would also need to get ranks of a sorted map. I would like to use the index as rank (1,2,3...) What might be the best way to do this with maps as here its not possible to obtain the index. It is rather inconvinient to create a list from the map each time

Comment: If you want an index, you'll really need to use a `List<SomeObject>` instead in combination with a suitable `Comparator<SomeObject>` or maybe `Comparable<SomeObject>`. The `SomeObject` in turn can then hold the original map key and value. A `Set<SomeObject>` may also be suitable, you'll only count the index yourself.

Answer (score 27):

You still can use `Collections.min` with a custom `Comparator` to get the `Map.Entry` with the lower value:

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
map.put("1.1", 1.1);
map.put("0.1", 0.1);
map.put("2.1", 2.1);
Map.Entry<String, Double> min = Collections.min(map.entrySet(), new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry1, Map.Entry<String, Double> entry2) {
        return entry1.getValue().compareTo(entry2.getValue());
    }
});
System.out.printf("%s: %f", min.getKey(), min.getValue()); // 0.1: 0.100000
```

With Java 8+:

```
Map.Entry<String, Double> min = Collections.min(map.entrySet(),
                                                Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

Answer (score 15):

Java8 One-Liner

```java
Key key = Collections.min(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey()
```

Answer (score 5):

> In traditional way, I would have to
>   sort the map according to the values,
>   and take the first/last one. thanks

No, you wouldn't. You would have to iterate through all values and at each step compare the current element with the smallest one seen so far. That's O(n), compared with O(n*log(n)) for sorting - a potentially *huge* difference.

BTW, this is exactly how `Collections.min()` works.

Comment: If I sort the map according to the values, I get a new sorted Map, for example:
(A,1),(B,2),(C,3)
Here, I can take just the key of the first element.

Comment: @chris-gr: it takes much longer and uses more memory than necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Using Java 8 streams:

```
return map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

Or

```
return map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

But if you want to do it multiple times, then definitely give [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) a look.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to use a Google Collections BiMap:

```
     String minKey = HashBiMap.create(map).inverse().get(Collections.min(map.values()));
```

Or something like that (not tested).

Comment: Nice oneliner, but not really efficient.

Comment: But it can be that the values are of the same value (double) Which key do I get in this case?

Comment: @chris, it has to do with what is the key and what is the value in the map, not their types. In the end, at runtime, they are all Object anyway.

Comment: @BalusC, Certainly not, but that may not matter. If the map is large and often used bidirectionally, it could be stored in a BiMap in the first place. inverse() is a cheap operation in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Using java 8 (and static imports). We can make @superfav's solution much tidier:

```
Map<String, Double> myMap;
String theKeyWithHighestValue = Collections.min(myMap.entrySet(), comparingDouble(Entry::getValue)).getKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 we can get easily:

```
Double minValue = map.entrySet().stream().min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getValue();
Double maxValue = map.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getValue();
```

Comment: nice, but can lead to errors using `.get()`.  These create an 'Optional.get()' without 'isPresent()' warning.  Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686215/avoid-nosuchelementexception-with-stream) for some safer alternatives

Answer (score 1):

In order to do it efficiently, you may want to define your own data structure, such that it implements the Map interface,but also allows efficient getMin() operation.

This can be done using two internal data structures: a map and a tree (or heap data structure). Each time a new pair (K,V) is added, add them to the map, and also to the tree (as a single entry). This allows O(1) time for get(Key) operations, and O(log n) time for addition, removal, and getMin operations.