# Collection.min Query For HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have Declared a HashMap as

HashMap  minMaxVal = new HashMap();
with K,V as Integer,Float[]

Would Like to retrieve the Min value from hashMap. Overriding the Min Function of collection is only solution for this scenario. How do I approach this.

Comment: Why are you using `Float[]` instead of `float[]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Map<Integer, Float[]>` can be converted to a `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Float[]>>` using [`Map.entrySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29). Once you have this set, you can use [`Collections.min()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to find the minimum value. Your comparator will have to decide how two `Map.Entry<Integer, Float[]>` instances compare.

I could have given you an example, but you didn't say what *min* meant in your case.

Comment: @ JB Nizet :: "min" here means extracting the Minimum or the lowest value for the given Collection... Thank You

Comment: Do you want the minimum key (Integer), or the minimum value (Float[]). If the latter, how do you compare Float[] instances? Is [1, 4] smaller or greater than [0, null, 12]?

Comment: My scenario is this  k,v [0-->(10.6,4.6)]                                                     [1-->(5.7,8.9)]                                                      I am suppose to extract the lowest the number among the values in the collection.

Comment: Then the best you can do is iterate through each value in the map (use Map.values() to get the values of the Map), and then iterate through each float of each array and keep the minimum value. It would be slightly easier if you used a Map<Integer, List<Float>> because then you would just have one iteration, and you could use Collections.min() to find the minimum value of each of the List<Float>. Next time you ask a question, make it much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

see this question : [Get minvalue of a Map(Key,Double)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776176/get-minvalue-of-a-mapkey-double)

expecially see how to use a custom comparator, cause float[] is not directly (nor easily) comparable.