# Avoid NoSuchElementException with Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have the following `Stream`:

```
Stream<T> stream = stream();

T result = stream.filter(t -> {
    double x = getX(t);
    double y = getY(t);
    return (x == tx && y == ty);
}).findFirst().get();

return result;
```

However, there is not always a result which gives me the following error:

> NoSuchElementException: No value present

So how can I return a `null` if there is no value present?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can use [`Optional.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-), it's much simpler than checking `isPresent`:

```
T result = stream.filter(t -> {
    double x = getX(t);
    double y = getY(t);
    return (x == tx && y == ty);
}).findFirst().orElse(null);

return result;
```

Answer (score 33):

[`Stream#findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) which exists specifically so that you don't need to operate on `null` values.

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a
>   value is present, `isPresent()` will return `true` and `get()` will return
>   the value.

Otherwise, [`Optional#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

> If a value is present in this `Optional`, returns the value, otherwise
>   throws `NoSuchElementException`.

An `Optional` will never expose its value if it is `null`.

**If you really have to**, just check `isPresent()` and return `null` yourself.

```
Stream<T> stream = stream();

Optional<T> result = stream.filter(t -> {
    double x = getX(t);
    double y = getY(t);
    return (x == tx && y == ty);
}).findFirst();

if (result.isPresent()) 
    return result.get();
return null;
```

Comment: Or just go with returning an `Optional`, which may have some advantages over returning null.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method for replacing the [`Optional.get`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get()) (which more likely than not fails the user's intentions with a NoSuchElementException) is with a more verbose API introduced in JDK10 termed as [`Optional.orElseThrow()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()). In [author's words](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140281) -

> `Optional.get()` is an "attractive nuisance" and is too tempting for
>   programmers, leading to frequent errors. *People don't expect a getter
>   to throw an exception.* A replacement API for `Optional.get()` with
>   equivalent semantics should be added.

***Note*** :- The underlying implementation of both these APIs is same, yet the latter reads out more clearly that a NoSuchElementException would be thrown by default if the value is not present which inlines to the existing [`Optional.orElseThrow​(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)) implementation used by consumers as an explicit alternate.

Comment: More precisely to answer ['Optional.get()' without 'isPresent()' check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725445/optional-get-without-ispresent-check) marked as duplicate of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to continue using the object and not throw any exception, then

`Optional.isPresent(object)`
is the way to go