# Optional value should only be accessed after calling isPresent()

Tags: java, sonarqube

How can I change my code according to Sonar lint rules?

My code is below:

```java
public interface TokenParser {
    public Optional<String> getUserName();
}

public class JWTTokenParser implements TokenParser {

    private Optional<Jwt> getJwt() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!authentication.isAuthenticated() || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable((Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal());
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getUserName() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(getJwt().get().getClaimAsString("preferred_username"));
    }
}
```

I could not pass the Sonar rules. How can I change my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Optional.get()' without 'isPresent()' check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725445/optional-get-without-ispresent-check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is warning about the `get` is called without checking `isPresent`. Which will throw `NoSuchElementException` if no value is present, it violates the idea of using `Optional`.

```java
    @Override
    public Optional<String> getUserName() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(getJwt().get().getClaimAsString("preferred_username"));
    }
```

Since `getUserName()` is also returning an `Optional`, we may use [`Optional#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) to convert `Optional<Jwt>` to `Optional<String>`

```
 return getJwt().map(jwt -> jwt.getClaimAsString("preferred_username")));
```

`map` method will take care different case for us, as below:

| getJwt() | jwt.getClaimAsString("preferred_username") | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| empty | will not call | Optioal.empty() |
| empty | will not call | Optioal.empty() |
| not empty | return null | Optioal.empty() |
| not empty | return non null value | Optional with non null value |