# Return the Minvalue and key pair from the For Loop/ArrayList in Java Android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I have this function which returns entry.getKey() and entry.getValue(). When I return it the function, I will get response like below

```
 Log.d("myTag", entry.getKey() + " " +entry.getValue());


healthy  0.345
unhealthy  0.0
healthy  0.543
```

From this list, what I want is the pair with the minimum entry.getValue().

example : Above list should only return ***unhealthy  0.0***

I tried by Collections minimum to return, but it was clashing with the int type and list type... How can I return the pair with minimum entry.getValue()?

**Note: refer the Log.d and returning recognitions **

```
    public List<Recognition>recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap, final  int sensorOriwentation){

        Bitmap resized_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true);

        List<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<>();
        inputImageBuffer = loadImage(resized_bitmap,sensorOriwentation);
        tensorClassifier.run(inputImageBuffer.getBuffer(),probabilityImageBuffer.getBuffer().rewind());

        Map<String,Float> labelledProbability = new TensorLabel(labels,
                probabilityProcessor.process(probabilityImageBuffer)).getMapWithFloatValue();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Float>entry : labelledProbability.entrySet()){

            recognitions.add(new Recognition(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
            Log.d("myTag", "entry.getKey():  "+ entry.getKey() + "   " + "entry.getValue():  "+entry.getValue());

        }


        return recognitions;
    }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776176/get-minvalue-of-a-mapkey-double) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do below changes in your java code to return list with minimum value:

```
public List<Recognition>recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap, final  int sensorOriwentation){

        Bitmap resized_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true);

        List<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<>();
        inputImageBuffer = loadImage(resized_bitmap,sensorOriwentation);
        tensorClassifier.run(inputImageBuffer.getBuffer(),probabilityImageBuffer.getBuffer().rewind());

        Map<String,Float> labelledProbability = new TensorLabel(labels,
                probabilityProcessor.process(probabilityImageBuffer)).getMapWithFloatValue();
        Integer i= new Integer(0);
        String minKey = null;
        Float minValue = new Float(0.0);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Float>entry : labelledProbability.entrySet()){
            if(i==0) {
              minValue = entry.getValue();
              minKey = entry.getKey();
            }else if(minValue > entry.getValue()){
              minValue = entry.getValue();
              minKey = entry.getKey();
            }  
            i++;
            Log.d("myTag", "entry.getKey():  "+ entry.getKey() + "   " + "entry.getValue():  "+entry.getValue());

        }
        if(minKey != null){
          recognitions.add(new Recognition(minKey,minValue));
        }
        return recognitions;
    }
```

Here, I am finding entry with minimum value and adding into "recognitions" arrayList if entry exists.